# stored procedure not working php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a simple stored procedure for insert with parameter as table name and insert value.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TEST3; 
CREATE  PROCEDURE TEST3(IN tab_name VARCHAR(40),IN IDVALUE VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
 SET @t2 = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ? (id) VALUES(?)');
 PREPARE stmt4 FROM @t2;
 EXECUTE stmt4 USING @tab_name, @IDVALUE;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt4;
END  $$
DELIMITER ;
```

It is being created but when I call it it throws following error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? (id) VALUES(?)' at line 1

What is that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this you can do it like this

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE TEST3(IN tab_name VARCHAR(40), IN IDVALUE VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
 SET @t2 = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `', tab_name, '` (id) VALUES(?)'),
     @id = idvalue;

 PREPARE stmt4 FROM @t2;
 EXECUTE stmt4 USING @id;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt4;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d490/1)** demo

---

Two major issues with your original code are:

1. You can't prepare a statement without an object identifier, table name in your case. Object identifiers are static. To work around this you should concatenate a table name into your statement.
2. Local (`IDVALUE` in your case) and user (session) variables (`@IDVALUE`) are two completely different beasts. And `EXECUTE ... USING` can work only with latter. Therefore you need to assign a value of `IDVALUE` to a session variable (`@id` in my example).

Further reading:

- [Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html)
- [User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html)
- [EXECUTE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/execute.html)

Comment: perfect answer. i had tried with concatenate 'tab_name' but had no idea about the second issue that u mentioned.

Comment: is this statement immune to sql injection with respect to parameter IDVALUE?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query, it worked for me in phpmyadmin

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sample_procedure`(IN `10` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER SELECT "print this";
```